# How to showcase app images using slick js carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

im working on my portfolio page and i want to showcase my app in a carousel view. However the images are shaped vertically so when i try to use them it doesn't align the images the way i want it. Infact, they are less organised and im using slick js for the carousel for my portfolio but they are not aligned properly.

I also want to move the carousel to the left of the page so that it looks more organised as i want to add other carousels to the same page.

[image: vertical carousel]

Here is my code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>stackoverflow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="slick-theme.css">

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"> <img style="max-width:200px; margin-top: -30px;" src="muss sig.png"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Contact <i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

      <div class="img-area">
        <div class="img-slide">
          <div class="single-img">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
            <h2>Guest Login Page</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="single-img">
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
            <h2>Main Menu</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="single-img">
            <img src="3.jpg" alt="">
            <h2>Room Service Menu</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="single-img">
            <img src="4.jpg" alt="">
            <h2>Cleaning Service Page</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="single-img">
            <img src="5.jpg" alt="">
            <h2>Tv Channel Menu</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="single-img">
            <img src="6.jpg" alt="">
            <h2>Toiletries Menu</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="slick.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.img-slide').slick({

    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 7000,
    arrows: true,
    dots: true,
    fade: true,
    speed: 2000,
    infinite: true,
    cssEase: 'ease-in-out',
    loop: true

  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.single-img h2{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 8%;
    color: lawngreen;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.img-area{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 40%;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.img-area .img-slide{
    box-shadow: 0 20px 50px -25px #000;
}

.img-area .img-slide-track{
    transition: all Is cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}
.img-area .single-img{
    width: auto;
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.img-area .single-img img{
    width: 50%;
    transition: all Is cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    transform: scale(1.2);

}
.img-area .single-img.slick-active img{
    transform: scale(1);
    animation: animate 8s 1 ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes animate{
    from{
        transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px);
    }
}
```

Comment: You say that your implementation of Slick "doesn't align the images the way I want it". What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You know how like my app images are vertical shaped shown in the image i provided. I want the images to be fixed with the carousel so that there isn't a huge space around the outside border of the image. If you look closely at the screenshot i've taken, you can see the two arrows from the carousel pointing left and right, i want the right arrow to be closer to the vertical image but because of the border around it, it's not working.

Comment: It looks like your issue might be with the `width: 50%` that you are adding to your `img` and the height on your `.single-img` container. You could try using a static pixel width on your image and removing this height in order to let that be determined by Slick.